# space between CSS Sprite menu buttons with CSS

Tags: css, css-sprites

I have a vertical CSS sprite menu.

I would like to realize a (at example) 3 pixel space between each of the vertical buttons.
Is it possible to create this spaces with CSS?

or is the only option to resize the Sprite with all buttons and set all positions new in the CSS file?

Comment: Hey, what's the problem? Are the images cut off or are you trying to create space between the elements? CSS cannot change images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's simple to use but the main problem with your `markup`. write like this:

```
ul#menu {
    clear: both;
    float: right;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#menu li {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

& remove `<br>` from your `html`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

Assuming that each button uses the background independently of the other buttons, you can simply put a margin on each one:

for example:

```
#menu li{
   background: url(../urlToSprite) /* set positions elsewhere */
   margin-bottom:3px;
}
```